# Creating an L Shape Border Around an <li>

Tags: html, css

I want to create a border of 'L' share around an `<li>`.
Is this possible even? I have similar things with `<div>` but my scenario required the 'L' shape with an `<li>`
Something like:

[image]

Comment: Maybe add an example (draw it in paint or whatever) so people can actually help you :)

Comment: css for `border-left` and `border-bottom` would work, right? Or do I missunderstand the question?

Comment: Please see this code.. May work Thanks to **@RaJeshRiJo** he helped me. https://jsfiddle.net/fswdbywd/2/

Answer (score 2):

Try something by using `:before` and `:after` as like below snippet. Hope it helps.

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

li::before {
  background-color: red;
  bottom: -5px;
  content: "";
  height: 20px;
  left: -10px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
}

li::after {
  background-color: red;
  bottom: -5px;
  content: "";
  height: 2px;
  left: -10px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>Welcome</li>
</ul>
```

Update: As per **JaTurna** comment on the answer, we can achieve by changing few lines of code.

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

li::before {
  background-color: red;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
  height: 20px;
  left: -20px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
}

li::after {
  border-bottom: 2px dashed red;
  bottom: 10px;
  content: "";
  left: -20px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Hi</li>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>Welcome</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I don't think he wants this.. I guess he want something like this
-- Ups! I can't show it here.

**Some Clue**
He wants something like directory listing lines

Comment: @JaTurna check the updated answer.

Comment: Hmm, May be more css will help him to get desired design... Thanks for your response!

Comment: As  new answer is blocked. My answer is in this comment https://jsfiddle.net/fswdbywd/2/